# Using FileExtd.lib with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've been using GetFileInformationByHandleEx routine in a VS2005 project. At that time the function was available with FileExtd.h and FileExtd.lib which you had to manually download it. Now I want to migrate the project to VS2010 and I've seen that there is a FileExtd.lib that is shipped with the new SDK.

In VS2010 the GetFileInformationByHandleEx is declared in winbase.h, but in order to keep compatibility with WindowXP I had to declare an _WIN32_WINNT with a lower value (like NTDDI_WINXP) that disables the routine definition. Otherwise it will statically link to kernel32.dll (where the routine is not available on WinXP). Therefore I think the solution would be to use the old FileExtd.h in combination with the VS2010 version of FileExtd.lib. But if I do that, I have the following linking errors:

```
1>fileextd.lib(fileextd.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RtlSetLastWin32Error@4 referenced in function _BaseSetLastNTError@4
1>fileextd.lib(fileextd.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__NtWaitForSingleObject@12 referenced in function _GetFileInformationByHandleEx@16
```

I tried to keep the declaration from winbase.h and declare FileExtd.lib before kernel32.lib, but it still links to kernel32.dll.

Also, is it ok to combine libraries that were compiled with other versions of Visual Studio? I'm asking this because of I'm using the VS2005 version if FileExtd.lib in my VS2010 project, it compiles and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encouter the same problem. Specify `FileExtd.lib` *before* `kernel32.lib` in `link.exe` command line should be fine. Here is my setting in Visual Studio 2010 which running under Windows 10 while building target for XP.

Under Configuration Propery / Linker / Input / Additional dependencies, add `FileExtd.lib` *before* `%(AdditionalDependencies)`.

[image: Link Setting]

The generated DLL do not require symbol `GetFileInformationByHandle` from kernel32.dll, which can be assured by running `dumpbin` utility.

```
dumpbin /imports path\to\dll-or-exe | grep SetFileInformationByHandle
              464 SetFileInformationByHandle  <-- disappered
```